# Flutter: json_serializable from json file path

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:gameP/src/country_list.json'
    as countryList;

var a = CountryList.fromJson(countryList);
```

json file

```
[
  {
    "country": "AD",
    "lat": 42.546245,
    "long": 1.601554,
    "name": "Andorra"
  },
  {
    "country": "AE",
    "lat": 23.424076,
    "long": 53.847818,
    "name": "United Arab Emirates"
  }, 
  ....
]
```

json_serializable

```
@JsonSerializable()
class CountryList {
  final List<CountryListDetail> countryList;

  CountryList(this.countryList);

  factory CountryList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CountryListFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CountryListToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class CountryListDetail {
  final String? country;
  final String? name;
  final double? lat;
  final double? long;

  CountryListDetail(
      this.countryCode, this.countryName, this.lat, this.long);

  factory CountryListDetail.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CountryListDetailFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CountryListDetailToJson(this);
}
```

I am trying to convert this json file inside my directory using the `json_serializable` package.

```
The argument type 'CountryListModel' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<CountryListModel>?'.

The name 'countryList' refers to an import prefix, so it must be followed by '.'.
Try correcting the name to refer to something other than a prefix, or renaming the prefix.
```

However, I am getting these issues. How can I import this json file and convert into `var = a` using `.fromJson();`?

Comment: change the name ``countryList `` afaik :/ as it says you are using the ``countryList`` two different places for two different purpose

Comment: change the name countryList from`` final List<CountryListDetail> countryList;`` to something else or  ``import 'package:gameP/src/country_list.json'
    as countryList;`` to something eelse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change one of countryList names  for example :

```
import 'package:gameP/src/country_list.json' as countryListClass;
```